# How calculate similarity between two point clouds

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, python

I have two point clouds.
How do I calculate the similarity between them?

example

[image]

In the image above the similarity is around 0.80

[image]

and the similarity here is 0.30

Comment: Usually one would calculate the pointwise similarity using a [similarity measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_measure) and use the mean and standard deviation to describe the similarity between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem typically occurs in hierarchical clustering where the distance $D$ between clusters needs to be computed, whilst only a distance $d$ between individual points is defined (e.g. the Euclidean distance).

There are different standard solutions named *single linkage*, *complete linkage* or *average linkage*, e.g.
$$D_{single}(C_1,C_2) = \min\{d(x,y)\,\mid\, x\in C_1, y\in C_2 \}$$